# What characters are valid in couchdb-lucene keys?

Tags: lucene, couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I am able to store values in couchdb-lucene with whatever key I like, but it seems that if the key includes any chars outside of [0-9a-zA-Z_] any search fails.

Does anyone know what chars are valid and/or how to properly escape special chars in searches such that special chars can be used?

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) shows how to escape special characters and also gives a list of such characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, escaping as mentioned on that page does not work for the key names. "a-b" and "a\-b" will both fail to find the field.

Comment: Depending on your schema, phrase queries may work. Try `"a-b"` and `"a\-b"` (with the quotes). Also, verify that the field is getting added to the index with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

All UTF-8 characters should work. I've just verified that I can search for items with é, for example.

A little more information on how you're querying would help, though given the age of this ticket perhaps you've moved on.